# how to use saiku api webapp

Tags: api, web-applications, saiku

I am new to saiku ,recently I want to use saiku api

```
eg:http:///saiku/serverdocs/resource_QueryResource.html
```

when I access 
    my url :[your saiku domain]

then I  select one cube and some Dimensions,I could see the data,then   I saved this query(called 111111).when I use the api which the doc mentions

```
eg: Mount Point: /rest/saiku/{username}/query.
```

I try to access the url

```
http:///saiku/admin/query/111111
```

on firefox

There are some questions which told me that HTTP Status 404 - /saiku/admin/query/111111

```
now I don't know how to use the api which the url:http:////saiku/serverdocs  mentionde.  I hope someone could help me
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access repository. This is where all queries are stored:

http://demo.analytical-labs.com/saiku/serverdocs/resource_BasicRepositoryResource.html

The following resources are applicable:

```
/saiku/{username}/repository
/saiku/{username}/repository/{queryname}
```

I created a query named 111111.saiku and it works perfectly:

http://demo.analytical-labs.com/saiku/rest/saiku/admin/repository/111111.saiku

Comment: I tried the way just as you said.Now I could get a MDX description.Someone want to get the queryData. If they access this url, they only could get MDX, not the data.I don't know how to do it .Thanks again.

Comment: Can't find it, sorry. You can get list of some queries using http://demo.analytical-labs.com/saiku/rest/saiku/admin/query/ and then results using something like http://demo.analytical-labs.com/saiku/rest/saiku/admin/query/e0a7648b-e9c2-4e65-ad85-a06a1b751728/result. Have no idea what these queries are and how they link to repository. You can try asking guys from Saiku directly on their support forum.